# Can we multiply two bytes directly by using * operator directly

Tags: java

I need to perform the following operation on a byte  `(2*x*x)+x`  where x is a single byte. Can i perform that operation directly as we will do for int. If no how can we perform above operation.

Comment: What is the `^` symbol? Is it **XOR** (programming notation) or **to the power** (mathematical notation)?

Comment: Yes i have tried directly. But i am not sure whether the output will be correct or not

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the following?

```
byte x =
int f = 2 * x * x + x;
```

As an exercise I suggest you print out the results of every possibility byte value and see if you get the expected value. There is only 256 possible byte values.

Comment: yes, whatever we do the compiler will not object. But my doubt is whether the output is correct or not?

Comment: As long as you assume the byte is signed, i.e. between -128 and 127, the answer will be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Java integer arithmetic is two-complement; that means that (as long there are enough bits to write down the values) lengthning or shortening the field does not affect the result.

NOTE1: Check for overflows. If the result is not in the 128 / -127 range it will not fit in a byte (or 255 / 0 for unsigned).

NOTE2: Float and double are not part of integer arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently you believe that the operator exists because the compiler allows it but you don't believe that the JVM will compute the result correctly. Why?

And how hard is this to test? Bytes only have 256 values each.

Answer (score 0):

There can be two different cases:

`byte a = 2; byte b = 2; byte c = a*b`
it is correct but

`byte a = 22; byte b = 22; byte c = a*b`
it is not correct.
because while assigning value to a and b we given value less than 127 but after multiplication the value is longer than one byte that is why we need a bigger datatype to store value of c.

for that case you can use `int c = a*b;`